# Prove by induction floor and ceiling

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I couldn't solve below question ... I was able to start the solution .. but I couldn't turn left side to be same as write side in the inductive step:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that there is a perfectly straightforward non-inductive proof. Requirement you to use induction is poor pædagogy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you only need to show

$$\left\lceil \frac{n+1}{m}\right\rceil - \left\lceil \frac nm \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n+m}{m} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n+m-1}{m}\right\rfloor$$

Now the LHS is either $0$ or $1$, usually $0$. So is the RHS.

When is LHS $1$? When is RHS $1$?

> When $\frac nm \in \mathbb N$, both LHS and RHS are equal to 1. Otherwise they are both zeros. Therefore, $$\left\lceil \frac{n+1}{m}\right\rceil - \left\lceil \frac nm \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n+m}{m} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n+m-1}{m}\right\rfloor \tag1$$ $$\left\lceil \frac nm \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n+m-1}{m}\right\rfloor \text{ (from last step)} \tag 2$$ $(1)+(2)$, then we have $$ \left\lceil \frac{n+1}{m}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n+m}{m} \right\rfloor $$

Comment: still not sure how to fit this in inductive proof?

Comment: Add $\lceil \frac nm \rceil = \lfloor \frac{n+m-1}{m} \rfloor$

Comment: still not so clear for me ... could you give more details.

Comment: See my edit now.

Comment: I think equation 2 is from is by induction hypothesis, but not sure how did you come up with  equation 1?

Comment: That was explained in the line above (1).

Comment: Thank you.... I think its clear ... but are you sure this solution is using induction. I feel you  used equation 1 & 2... maybe there is any easier solution using induction only

Comment: Yes this is induction. On the contrary it's much easier to prove it without induction by just looking at the remainder when dividing $n$ by $m$.